# What would a dragon with a prehensile tail look like?

Tags: biology, magic

I have a human-like dragon that can hang upside down from trees by its tail and without the aid of its other limbs. What I am struggling with is how the scales on its tail have to be arranged to allow full flexibility while still allowing sufficient protection.

Comment: It would probably look like a dragon tail, rather than a duck tail or a fish tail.

Comment: How big is your dragon, there was a group of large extinct reptiles with prehensile tails that had a claw at the end. Drepanosauromorpha is clearly doing something really weird.

Comment: Your question is too story based. Worldbuilding doesn't handle "how do I describe" kinds of questions.

Comment: @elemtilas The criteria are TOO story based. I am surprised how many WBers seem to be blind to the word "too". Even if this question was story based. At worst, it is only about a description of a creature, which is a minor element of a work of fiction at best. As a worldbuilding element it can be construed as how part of a creature might function.

Comment: A prehensile tail on a dragon would be similar to how the body of a snake functions in wrapping itself around a branch. if a reptile like a snake can do without problems, then a dragon should be able to do likewise.

Comment: @a4android Many worldbuilders worldbuild do so for stories or games. Asking how to describe something like a tail contains many story based elements and can be entirely independent of worldbuilding. The OP should be editing the question to make it world building focused rather than asking us how to describe a prehensile dragon tail without using the words prehensile dragon tail. (That and the second question he threw in about scale arrangements which would be more on topic).

Comment: @Shadowzee "Asking how to describe something like a tail contains many story based elements and can be entirely independent of worldbuilding." Frankly, "contains many story based elements" that's something that anyone can hardly give credence to. Would you care to list them for everyone's enlightenment?

Comment: @a4android. "The tail was thick like a orcs leg. It hung loosely off the tree supporting the dragons entire weight.", "The tail was like a thick rope. Its scales formed into braid like shapes and the surface has a rough finish", "The tail was jet black, yet glimmered in the moonlight. I would of missed it if I didn't catch the twinkling as it swayed in the breeze.", "The tail was as thick as the trunk it was wrapped around. The bark of the tree splintered where the muscular tail had wrapped around it". Tell me, how would you describe my imaginary dragons tail? The one you know nothing about.

Comment: @shadoeese, perhaps he is looking for an answer from nature?

Comment: @GarretGang Perhaps he is.... but he needs to clarify it in the question or comments so we know for sure. I will gladly vote to open this question if it was asking for a good real world analogy, but as it is right now, its asking how to describe a tails appearance.

Comment: @Shadowzee How does that list the many story based elements you claim it contains? I grant the question isn't well framed, but that doesn't mean it's chockablock full of story based elements. Mere description trivially doesn't count.

Comment: @a4android He asked to describe a tail? how do you describe a tail without describing it?

Comment: @Shadowzee The question has been edited, but what he originally wrote was he didn't know how to describe it. Not exactly the same thing as asking for a description. The point is this isn't a story element, so those who VTC'ed the question as TOO story-based did so in error. PS: description is part of prose & while prose is used to tell stories this doesn't make it a story-based element. Just commonsense & logic, really.

Answer (score 5):

Some [geckos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crested_gecko) and chameleons have prehensile tails. For example, the [Indian chameleon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_chameleon), *Chamaeleo zeylanicus*:

[image: Indian chameleon]

*Indian chameleon,* Chamaeleo zeylanicus, *showing its prehensile tail. Photograph by [M.arunprasad](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:M.arunprasad), available on Wikimedia under the [GNU Free Documentation License](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/en:GNU_Free_Documentation_License).*

Comment: prehensile tails look the same in pretty much anything that has them, all that varies is hat they are covered in.